# Как вывести данные таблицы в виде массива через запятую (например, [5, 1, 2...]) из одного столбца PHP и MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'rent');
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `ocenka` FROM `reviews` ");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста попробуйте `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(ocenka AS CHAR)) FROM ...`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in D:\OpenServer\domains\LaCasa\addit-page.php:24 Stack trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\LaCasa\addit-page.php(24): mysqli_fetch_array() #1 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\LaCasa\addit-page.php on line 24

Comment: Вам больше не нужен цикл while. Весь результат из базы данных будет представлен в виде одной строки со значениями, разделенными запятыми.